# Пунктуация при "но"

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте, у меня есть вопрос.

Возьмем для примера следующее предложение:

> Он сжимал в руке маленький, но невероятно острый(,) нож.

Подскажите, какое правило регламентирует расстановку запятых в этом предложении. Я часто встречаю подобные предложения, но в одном случае запятая ставится лишь перед **но**, а в другом - еще и после слова **острый**.

Как я понял, если запятая ставится только перед **но**, то это ситуация перечисления свойств, в которой **но** можно опустить. А если запятая ставится еще и после слова **острый**?

Помогите разобраться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В приведенном вами предложении требуется одна запятая, которая верно стоит перед *но*. Перед противительными союзами (а, но, зато...) она ставится всегда: "Он красивый, но глупый", "Маша слезла хоть и неосторожно, зато быстро". При этом стоить помнить, что подобные противопоставления не являются обособляемыми оборотами, то есть не выделяются запятыми: "Иван ответил громко, да неверно и сел за парту".

Однако нередко возникают ситуации, в которых сразу после таких противопоставлений ставятся запятые, открывающие или закрывающие другие обороты: "Я вернулся с охоты уставший, но радостный, (начинается сравнительный оборот) как дурак" или "Гена, решивший поступить не хорошо, а плохо, (закрывается причастный оборот) был наказан". Под их влиянием, я полагаю, и возникают описанные вами сомнения.

Comment: Понял, спасибо за развернутый и понятный ответ.

А относительно запятой перед союзом "а" - разве запятая ставится всегда? Ведь союз "а" может употребляться в значении союза "и". Например: "Он посмотрел в небо а потом тяжело вздохнул".

Comment: @Максим пожалуйста, рад помочь! Не совсем точно. В вашем примере запятая обязательна! Попробую написать подробней, но позже.

Comment: @Максим союзы *а* и *и* могут быть присоединительными, т. е. выполнять схожие функции: ср. Он зашел домой, разделся и затем сел и Он зашел домой, разделся, а затем сел. Но утверждение, что *а* может употребляться в значении союза *и*, неверно. (И обратите внимание, что запятая перед *а* ставится!)

Comment: Благодарю за пояснения!